# How to ignore/solve "Repair" message from Powerpoint report generated by OpenXML with ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have been struggling with openxml for few days but finally able to generate the PPT reports in format as required. Just one thing which is not done is as soon as I download the report and open, it display the below message(in shot).
If I click repair, it opens fine but the users aren't happy with it. I have searched a lot but couldn't find out the answer.

I'll really appreciate the help.

[image]

The generated PPT contains tables which is the main reason I get this Repair message cuz' I don't get this in another report which contains just text.

**Code that generate table is present here:** 
[create dynamic table in powerpoint using openXML with c# and ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752781/create-dynamic-table-in-powerpoint-using-openxml-with-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

**Links to code and previous questions.**

[unable to generate second table in PPT report using openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818263/unable-to-generate-second-table-in-ppt-report-using-openxml)

[create dynamic table in powerpoint using openXML with c# and ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752781/create-dynamic-table-in-powerpoint-using-openxml-with-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it finally using Openxml sdk tool.

1.> Generated .pptx > repaired it > validated in SDK tool > all good.
2.> Generated .pptx > did not repair > validated in SDK tool > error at one place > checked the error. (it was creation of an object).

Used reflected code from point 1. and used the same snippet in my main code.

Done!

If you need more details. Please comment.

Comment: How did you validate it? I have the same problem.

Comment: @LionKing Dude, its been 5 years.. i dont have access to code and all now but have you followed the steps ?