# change table style text in openxml for powerpoint generatron

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have this code using openxml sdk which generates table in PPT report.
This line is the reason for table style.

```
  tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}";
```

Style is :

[image]

I need to change the style and colors but I couldn't find anything for that. Please help.

```
private D.Table GenerateTable(int projectID, string reportType)
    {
        // Declare and instantiate table  
        D.Table table = new D.Table();

        // Specify the required table properties for the table 
        D.TableProperties tableProperties = new D.TableProperties() { FirstRow = true, BandRow = false };
        D.TableStyleId tableStyleId = new D.TableStyleId();
        tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}";

        tableProperties.Append(tableStyleId);
        D.TableGrid tableGrid1 = new D.TableGrid();
        System.Data.DataTable dtData = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (reportType == "projcharter")
        {
            //tblXBenefit
            dtData = GetBenefit(projectID);

            // Declare and instantiate tablegrid and colums 
            //D.TableGrid tableGrid1 = new D.TableGrid();
            D.GridColumn gridColumn1 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 1848000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn2 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn3 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn4 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };

            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn1);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn2);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn3);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn4);
        }
        table.Append(tableProperties);
        table.Append(tableGrid1);

        // Instantiate the table header row 
        D.TableRow tableHRow = new D.TableRow() { Height = 0L };
        for (int column = 0; column < dtData.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            tableHRow.Append(CreateTextCell(dtData.Columns[column].ToString()));
        }
        table.Append(tableHRow);

        // Instantiate the table data row 
        for (int row = 0; row < dtData.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            // Instantiate the table row 
            D.TableRow tableRow = new D.TableRow() { Height = 0L };
            for (int column = 0; column < dtData.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                tableRow.Append(CreateTextCell(dtData.Rows[row][column].ToString()));
            }
            table.Append(tableRow);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Links to previous questions:
[create dynamic table in powerpoint using openXML with c# and ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752781/create-dynamic-table-in-powerpoint-using-openxml-with-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

[unable to generate second table in PPT report using openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818263/unable-to-generate-second-table-in-ppt-report-using-openxml)

[How to ignore/solve "Repair" message from Powerpoint report generated by OpenXML with ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863116/how-to-ignore-solve-repair-message-from-powerpoint-report-generated-by-openxml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. 
So what I did was, I created a new ppt > inserted tables with required design manually in it and then saved it as ppt xml (you will see this option in save as).

Open that xml search for tablestyleid and use that value in the code.